# Laravel RESTful Api Curl could not create URL in windows terminal

Tags: php, rest, curl, laravel

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/laravel-4-a-start-at-a-restful-api-updated--net-29785

This commad:

```
curl -i --user firstuser:first_password -d 'url=http://google.com&description=A Search Engine' localhost/l4api/public/index.php/api/v1/url
```

should return:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Tue, 21 May 2013 19:10:52 GMT
Content-Type: application/json

{"error":false,"message":"URL created"}
```

However, It prints out the HTML content instead:

```
Node&&this.parentNode.removeChild(this)})},each:function(t){return r.every.call(
this,function(e,n){return t.call(e,n,e)!==!1}),this},filter:function(t){return Z
(t)?this.not(this.not(t)):n(s.call(this,function(e){return S.matches(e,t)}))},ad
d:function(t,e){return n(N(this.concat(n(t,e))))},is:function(t){return this.len
gth>0&&S.matches(this[0],t)},not:function(e){var i=[];if(Z(e)&&e.call!==t)this.e
ach(function(t){e.call(this,t)||i.push(this)});else{var r="string"==typeof e?thi
s.filter(e):M(e)&&Z(e.item)?o.call(e):n(e);this.forEach(function(t){r.indexOf(t)
<0&&i.push(t)})}return n(i)},has:function(t){return this.filter(function(){retur
n D(t)?n.contains(this,t):n(this).find(t).size()})},eq:function(t){return-1===t?
this.slice(t):this.slice(t,+t+1)},first:function(){var t=this[0];return t&&!D(t)
?t:n(t)},last:function(){var t=this[this.length-1];return t&&!D(t)?t:n(t)},find:
function(t){var e,i=this;return e="object"==typeof t?n(t).filter(function(){var
t=this;return r.some.call(i,function(e){return n.contains(e,t)})}):1==this.lengt
h?n(S.qsa(this[0],t)):this.map(function(){return S.qsa(this,t)})},closest:functi
on(t,e){var i=this[0],r=!1;for("object"==typeof t&&(r=n(t));i&&!(r?r.indexOf(i)>
=0:S.matches(i,t));)i=i!==e&&!_(i)&&i.parentNode;return n(i)},parents:function(t
){for(var e=[],i=this;i.length>0;)i=n.map(i,function(t){return(t=t.parentNode)&&
!_(t)&&e.indexOf(t)<0?(e.push(t),t):void 0});return B(e,t)},parent:function(t){r
eturn B(N(this.pluck("parentNode")),t)},children:function(t){return B(this.map(f
unction(){return V(this)}),t)},contents:function(){return this.map(function(){re
turn o.call(this.childNodes)})},siblings:function(t){return B(this.map(function(
t,e){return s.call(V(e.parentNode),function(t){return t!==e})}),t)},empty:functi
on(){return this.each(function(){this.innerHTML=""})},pluck:function(t){return n
.map(this,function(e){return e[t]})},show:function(){return this.each(function()
{"none"==this.style.display&&(this.style.display=""),"none"==getComputedStyle(th
is,"").getPropertyValue("display")&&(this.style.display=I(this.nodeName))})},rep
laceWith:function(t){return this.before(t).remove()},wrap:function(t){var e=Z(t)
;if(this[0]&&!e)var i=n(t).get(0),r=i.parentNode||this.length>1;return this.each
(function(o){n(this).wrapAll(e?t.call(this,o):r?i.cloneNode(!0):i)})},wrapAll:fu
nction(t){if(this[0]){n(this[0]).before(t=n(t));for(var e;(e=t.children()).lengt
h;)t=e.first();n(t).append(this)}return this},wrapInner:function(t){var e=Z(t);r
eturn this.each(function(i){var r=n(this),o=r.contents(),s=e?t.call(this,i):t;o.
length?o.wrapAll(s):r.append(s)})},unwrap:function(){return this.parent().each(f
unction(){n(this).replaceWith(n(this).children())}),this},clone:function(){retur
n this.map(function(){return this.cloneNode(!0)})},hide:function(){return this.c
ss("display","none")},toggle:function(e){return this.each(function(){var i=n(thi
s);(e===t?"none"==i.css("display"):e)?i.show():i.hide()})},prev:function(t){retu
rn n(this.pluck("previousElementSibling")).filter(t||"*")},next:function(t){retu
rn n(this.pluck("nextElementSibling")).filter(t||"*")},html:function(t){return 0
===arguments.length?this.length>0?this[0].innerHTML:null:this.each(function(e){v
ar i=this.innerHTML;n(this).empty().append(J(this,t,e,i))})},text:function(e){re
turn 0===arguments.length?this.length>0?this[0].textContent:null:this.each(funct
ion(){this.textContent=e===t?"":""+e})},attr:function(n,i){var r;return"string"=
=typeof n&&i===t?0==this.length||1!==this[0].nodeType?t:"value"==n&&"INPUT"==thi
s[0].nodeName?this.val():!(r=this[0].getAttribute(n))&&n in this[0]?this[0][n]:r
:this.each(function(t){if(1===this.nodeType)if(D(n))for(e in n)X(this,e,n[e]);el
se X(this,n,J(this,i,t,this.getAttribute(n)))})},removeAttr:function(t){return t
his.each(function(){1===this.nodeType&&X(this,t)})},prop:function(e,n){return e=
P[e]||e,n===t?this[0]&&this[0][e]:this.each(function(t){this[e]=J(this,n,t,this[
e])})},data:function(e,n){var i=this.attr("data-"+e.replace(m,"-$1").toLowerCase
(),n);return null!==i?Y(i):t},val:function(t){return 0===arguments.length?this[0
]&&(this[0].multiple?n(this[0]).find("option").filter(function(){return this.sel
ected}).pluck("value"):this[0].value):this.each(function(e){this.value=J(this,t,
e,this.value)})},offset:function(t){if(t)return this.each(function(e){var i=n(th
is),r=J(this,t,e,i.offset()),o=i.offsetParent().offset(),s={top:r.top-o.top,left
:r.left-o.left};"static"==i.css("position")&&(s.position="relative"),i.css(s)});
if(0==this.length)return null;var e=this[0].getBoundingClientRect();return{left:
e.left+window.pageXOffset,top:e.top+window.pageYOffset,width:Math.round(e.width)
,height:Math.round(e.height)}},css:function(t,i){if(arguments.length<2){var r=th
is[0],o=getComputedStyle(r,"");if(!r)return;if("string"==typeof t)return r.style
[C(t)]||o.getPropertyValue(t);if(A(t)){var s={};return n.each(A(t)?t:[t],functio
n(t,e){s[e]=r.style[C(e)]||o.getPropertyValue(e)}),s}}var a="";if("string"==L(t)
)i||0===i?a=F(t)+":"+H(t,i):this.each(function(){this.style.removeProperty(F(t))
});else for(e in t)t[e]||0===t[e]?a+=F(e)+":"+H(e,t[e])+";":this.each(function()
{this.style.removeProperty(F(e))});return this.each(function(){this.style.cssTex
t+=";"+a})},index:function(t){return t?this.indexOf(n(t)[0]):this.parent().child
ren().indexOf(this[0])},hasClass:function(t){return t?r.some.call(this,function(
t){return this.test(W(t))},q(t)):!1},addClass:function(t){return t?this.each(fun
ction(e){i=[];var r=W(this),o=J(this,t,e,r);o.split(/\s+/g).forEach(function(t){
n(this).hasClass(t)||i.push(t)},this),i.length&&W(this,r+(r?" ":"")+i.join(" "))
}):this},removeClass:function(e){return this.each(function(n){return e===t?W(thi
s,""):(i=W(this),J(this,e,n,i).split(/\s+/g).forEach(function(t){i=i.replace(q(t
)," ")}),void W(this,i.trim()))})},toggleClass:function(e,i){return e?this.each(
function(r){var o=n(this),s=J(this,e,r,W(this));s.split(/\s+/g).forEach(function
(e){(i===t?!o.hasClass(e):i)?o.addClass(e):o.removeClass(e)})}):this},scrollTop:
function(e){if(this.length){var n="scrollTop"in this[0];return e===t?n?this[0].s
crollTop:this[0].pageYOffset:this.each(n?function(){this.scrollTop=e}:function()
{this.scrollTo(this.scrollX,e)})}},scrollLeft:function(e){if(this.length){var n=
"scrollLeft"in this[0];return e===t?n?this[0].scrollLeft:this[0].pageXOffset:thi
s.each(n?function(){this.scrollLeft=e}:function(){this.scrollTo(e,this.scrollY)}
)}},position:function(){if(this.length){var t=this[0],e=this.offsetParent(),i=th
is.offset(),r=d.test(e[0].nodeName)?{top:0,left:0}:e.offset();return i.top-=pars
eFloat(n(t).css("margin-top"))||0,i.left-=parseFloat(n(t).css("margin-left"))||0
,r.top+=parseFloat(n(e[0]).css("border-top-width"))||0,r.left+=parseFloat(n(e[0]
).css("border-left-width"))||0,{top:i.top-r.top,left:i.left-r.left}}},offsetPare
nt:function(){return this.map(function(){for(var t=this.offsetParent||a.body;t&&
!d.test(t.nodeName)&&"static"==n(t).css("position");)t=t.offsetParent;return t})
}},n.fn.detach=n.fn.remove,["width","height"].forEach(function(e){var i=e.replac
e(/./,function(t){return t[0].toUpperCase()});n.fn[e]=function(r){var o,s=this[0
];return r===t?$(s)?s["inner"+i]:_(s)?s.documentElement["scroll"+i]:(o=this.offs
et())&&o[e]:this.each(function(t){s=n(this),s.css(e,J(this,r,t,s[e]()))})}}),v.f
orEach(function(t,e){var i=e%2;n.fn[t]=function(){var t,o,r=n.map(arguments,func
tion(e){return t=L(e),"object"==t||"array"==t||null==e?e:S.fragment(e)}),s=this.
length>1;return r.length<1?this:this.each(function(t,a){o=i?a:a.parentNode,a=0==
e?a.nextSibling:1==e?a.firstChild:2==e?a:null,r.forEach(function(t){if(s)t=t.clo
neNode(!0);else if(!o)return n(t).remove();G(o.insertBefore(t,a),function(t){nul
l==t.nodeName||"SCRIPT"!==t.nodeName.toUpperCase()||t.type&&"text/javascript"!==
t.type||t.src||window.eval.call(window,t.innerHTML)})})})},n.fn[i?t+"To":"insert
"+(e?"Before":"After")]=function(e){return n(e)[t](this),this}}),S.Z.prototype=n
.fn,S.uniq=N,S.deserializeValue=Y,n.zepto=S,n}();window.Zepto=Zepto,void 0===win
dow.$&&(window.$=Zepto),function(t){function l(t){return t._zid||(t._zid=e++)}fu
nction h(t,e,n,i){if(e=p(e),e.ns)var r=d(e.ns);return(s[l(t)]||[]).filter(functi
on(t){return!(!t||e.e&&t.e!=e.e||e.ns&&!r.test(t.ns)||n&&l(t.fn)!==l(n)||i&&t.se
l!=i)})}function p(t){var e=(""+t).split(".");return{e:e[0],ns:e.slice(1).sort()
.join(" ")}}function d(t){return new RegExp("(?:^| )"+t.replace(" "," .* ?")+"(?
: |$)")}function m(t,e){return t.del&&!u&&t.e in f||!!e}function g(t){return c[t
]||u&&f[t]||t}function v(e,i,r,o,a,u,f){var h=l(e),d=s[h]||(s[h]=[]);i.split(/\s
/).forEach(function(i){if("ready"==i)return t(document).ready(r);var s=p(i);s.fn
=r,s.sel=a,s.e in c&&(r=function(e){var n=e.relatedTarget;return!n||n!==this&&!t
.contains(this,n)?s.fn.apply(this,arguments):void 0}),s.del=u;var l=u||r;s.proxy
=function(t){if(t=j(t),!t.isImmediatePropagationStopped()){t.data=o;var i=l.appl
y(e,t._args==n?[t]:[t].concat(t._args));return i===!1&&(t.preventDefault(),t.sto
pPropagation()),i}},s.i=d.length,d.push(s),"addEventListener"in e&&e.addEventLis
tener(g(s.e),s.proxy,m(s,f))})}function y(t,e,n,i,r){var o=l(t);(e||"").split(/\
s/).forEach(function(e){h(t,e,n,i).forEach(function(e){delete s[o][e.i],"removeE
ventListener"in t&&t.removeEventListener(g(e.e),e.proxy,m(e,r))})})}function j(e
,i){return(i||!e.isDefaultPrevented)&&(i||(i=e),t.each(E,function(t,n){var r=i[t
];e[t]=function(){return this[n]=x,r&&r.apply(i,arguments)},e[n]=b}),(i.defaultP
revented!==n?i.defaultPrevented:"returnValue"in i?i.returnValue===!1:i.getPreven
tDefault&&i.getPreventDefault())&&(e.isDefaultPrevented=x)),e}function T(t){var
e,i={originalEvent:t};for(e in t)w.test(e)||t[e]===n||(i[e]=t[e]);return j(i,t)}
var n,e=1,i=Array.prototype.slice,r=t.isFunction,o=function(t){return"string"==t
ypeof t},s={},a={},u="onfocusin"in window,f={focus:"focusin",blur:"focusout"},c=
{mouseenter:"mouseover",mouseleave:"mouseout"};a.click=a.mousedown=a.mouseup=a.m
ousemove="MouseEvents",t.event={add:v,remove:y},t.proxy=function(e,n){if(r(e)){v
ar i=function(){return e.apply(n,arguments)};return i._zid=l(e),i}if(o(n))return
 t.proxy(e[n],e);throw new TypeError("expected function")},t.fn.bind=function(t,
e,n){return this.on(t,e,n)},t.fn.unbind=function(t,e){return this.off(t,e)},t.fn
.one=function(t,e,n,i){return this.on(t,e,n,i,1)};var x=function(){return!0},b=f
unction(){return!1},w=/^([A-Z]|returnValue$|layer[XY]$)/,E={preventDefault:"isDe
faultPrevented",stopImmediatePropagation:"isImmediatePropagationStopped",stopPro
pagation:"isPropagationStopped"};t.fn.delegate=function(t,e,n){return this.on(e,
t,n)},t.fn.undelegate=function(t,e,n){return this.off(e,t,n)},t.fn.live=function
(e,n){return t(document.body).delegate(this.selector,e,n),this},t.fn.die=functio
n(e,n){return t(document.body).undelegate(this.selector,e,n),this},t.fn.on=funct
ion(e,s,a,u,f){var c,l,h=this;return e&&!o(e)?(t.each(e,function(t,e){h.on(t,s,a
,e,f)}),h):(o(s)||r(u)||u===!1||(u=a,a=s,s=n),(r(a)||a===!1)&&(u=a,a=n),u===!1&&
(u=b),h.each(function(n,r){f&&(c=function(t){return y(r,t.type,u),u.apply(this,a
rguments)}),s&&(l=function(e){var n,o=t(e.target).closest(s,r).get(0);return o&&
o!==r?(n=t.extend(T(e),{currentTarget:o,liveFired:r}),(c||u).apply(o,[n].concat(
i.call(arguments,1)))):void 0}),v(r,e,u,a,s,l||c)}))},t.fn.off=function(e,i,s){v
ar a=this;return e&&!o(e)?(t.each(e,function(t,e){a.off(t,i,e)}),a):(o(i)||r(s)|
|s===!1||(s=i,i=n),s===!1&&(s=b),a.each(function(){y(this,e,s,i)}))},t.fn.trigge
r=function(e,n){return e=o(e)||t.isPlainObject(e)?t.Event(e):j(e),e._args=n,this
.each(function(){"dispatchEvent"in this?this.dispatchEvent(e):t(this).triggerHan
dler(e,n)})},t.fn.triggerHandler=function(e,n){var i,r;return this.each(function
(s,a){i=T(o(e)?t.Event(e):e),i._args=n,i.target=a,t.each(h(a,e.type||e),function
(t,e){return r=e.proxy(i),i.isImmediatePropagationStopped()?!1:void 0})}),r},"fo
cusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick mousedown mouseup mousem
ove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave change select keydown keypress keyu
p error".split(" ").forEach(function(e){t.fn[e]=function(t){return t?this.bind(e
,t):this.trigger(e)}}),["focus","blur"].forEach(function(e){t.fn[e]=function(t){
return t?this.bind(e,t):this.each(function(){try{this[e]()}catch(t){}}),this}}),
t.Event=function(t,e){o(t)||(e=t,t=e.type);var n=document.createEvent(a[t]||"Eve
nts"),i=!0;if(e)for(var r in e)"bubbles"==r?i=!!e[r]:n[r]=e[r];return n.initEven
t(t,i,!0),j(n)}}(Zepto),function(t){function l(e,n,i){var r=t.Event(n);return t(
e).trigger(r,i),!r.isDefaultPrevented()}function h(t,e,i,r){return t.global?l(e|
|n,i,r):void 0}function p(e){e.global&&0===t.active++&&h(e,null,"ajaxStart")}fun
ction d(e){e.global&&!--t.active&&h(e,null,"ajaxStop")}function m(t,e){var n=e.c
ontext;return e.beforeSend.call(n,t,e)===!1||h(e,n,"ajaxBeforeSend",[t,e])===!1?
!1:void h(e,n,"ajaxSend",[t,e])}function g(t,e,n,i){var r=n.context,o="success";
n.success.call(r,t,o,e),i&&i.resolveWith(r,[t,o,e]),h(n,r,"ajaxSuccess",[e,n,t])
,y(o,e,n)}function v(t,e,n,i,r){var o=i.context;i.error.call(o,n,e,t),r&&r.rejec
tWith(o,[n,e,t]),h(i,o,"ajaxError",[n,i,t||e]),y(e,n,i)}function y(t,e,n){var i=
n.context;n.complete.call(i,e,t),h(n,i,"ajaxComplete",[e,n]),d(n)}function x(){}
function b(t){return t&&(t=t.split(";",2)[0]),t&&(t==f?"html":t==u?"json":s.test
(t)?"script":a.test(t)&&"xml")||"text"}function w(t,e){return""==e?t:(t+"&"+e).r
eplace(/[&?]{1,2}/,"?")}function E(e){e.processData&&e.data&&"string"!=t.type(e.
data)&&(e.data=t.param(e.data,e.traditional)),!e.data||e.type&&"GET"!=e.type.toU
pperCase()||(e.url=w(e.url,e.data),e.data=void 0)}function j(e,n,i,r){return t.i
sFunction(n)&&(r=i,i=n,n=void 0),t.isFunction(i)||(r=i,i=void 0),{url:e,data:n,s
uccess:i,dataType:r}}function S(e,n,i,r){var o,s=t.isArray(n),a=t.isPlainObject(
n);t.each(n,function(n,u){o=t.type(u),r&&(n=i?r:r+"["+(a||"object"==o||"array"==
o?n:"")+"]"),!r&&s?e.add(u.name,u.value):"array"==o||!i&&"object"==o?S(e,u,i,n):
e.add(n,u)})}var i,r,e=0,n=window.document,o=/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^
<]*)*<\/script>/gi,s=/^(?:text|application)\/javascript/i,a=/^(?:text|applicatio
n)\/xml/i,u="application/json",f="text/html",c=/^\s*$/;t.active=0,t.ajaxJSONP=fu
nction(i,r){if(!("type"in i))return t.ajax(i);var f,h,o=i.jsonpCallback,s=(t.isF
unction(o)?o():o)||"jsonp"+ ++e,a=n.createElement("script"),u=window[s],c=functi
on(e){t(a).triggerHandler("error",e||"abort")},l={abort:c};return r&&r.promise(l
),t(a).on("load error",function(e,n){clearTimeout(h),t(a).off().remove(),"error"
!=e.type&&f?g(f[0],l,i,r):v(null,n||"error",l,i,r),window[s]=u,f&&t.isFunction(u
)&&u(f[0]),u=f=void 0}),m(l,i)===!1?(c("abort"),l):(window[s]=function(){f=argum
ents},a.src=i.url.replace(/\?(.+)=\?/,"?$1="+s),n.head.appendChild(a),i.timeout>
0&&(h=setTimeout(function(){c("timeout")},i.timeout)),l)},t.ajaxSettings={type:"
GET",beforeSend:x,success:x,error:x,complete:x,context:null,global:!0,xhr:functi
on(){return new window.XMLHttpRequest},accepts:{script:"text/javascript, applica
tion/javascript, application/x-javascript",json:u,xml:"application/xml, text/xml
",html:f,text:"text/plain"},crossDomain:!1,timeout:0,processData:!0,cache:!0},t.
ajax=function(e){var n=t.extend({},e||{}),o=t.Deferred&&t.Deferred();for(i in t.
ajaxSettings)void 0===n[i]&&(n[i]=t.ajaxSettings[i]);p(n),n.crossDomain||(n.cros
sDomain=/^([\w-]+:)?\/\/([^\/]+)/.test(n.url)&&RegExp.$2!=window.location.host),
n.url||(n.url=window.location.toString()),E(n),n.cache===!1&&(n.url=w(n.url,"_="
+Date.now()));var s=n.dataType,a=/\?.+=\?/.test(n.url);if("jsonp"==s||a)return a
||(n.url=w(n.url,n.jsonp?n.jsonp+"=?":n.jsonp===!1?"":"callback=?")),t.ajaxJSONP
(n,o);var j,u=n.accepts[s],f={},l=function(t,e){f[t.toLowerCase()]=[t,e]},h=/^([
\w-]+:)\/\//.test(n.url)?RegExp.$1:window.location.protocol,d=n.xhr(),y=d.setReq
uestHeader;if(o&&o.promise(d),n.crossDomain||l("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpReques
t"),l("Accept",u||"*/*"),(u=n.mimeType||u)&&(u.indexOf(",")>-1&&(u=u.split(",",2
)[0]),d.overrideMimeType&&d.overrideMimeType(u)),(n.contentType||n.contentType!=
=!1&&n.data&&"GET"!=n.type.toUpperCase())&&l("Content-Type",n.contentType||"appl
ication/x-www-form-urlencoded"),n.headers)for(r in n.headers)l(r,n.headers[r]);i
f(d.setRequestHeader=l,d.onreadystatechange=function(){if(4==d.readyState){d.onr
eadystatechange=x,clearTimeout(j);var e,i=!1;if(d.status>=200&&d.status<300||304
==d.status||0==d.status&&"file:"==h){s=s||b(n.mimeType||d.getResponseHeader("con
tent-type")),e=d.responseText;try{"script"==s?(1,eval)(e):"xml"==s?e=d.responseX
ML:"json"==s&&(e=c.test(e)?null:t.parseJSON(e))}catch(r){i=r}i?v(i,"parsererror"
,d,n,o):g(e,d,n,o)}else v(d.statusText||null,d.status?"error":"abort",d,n,o)}},m
(d,n)===!1)return d.abort(),v(null,"abort",d,n,o),d;if(n.xhrFields)for(r in n.xh
rFields)d[r]=n.xhrFields[r];var T="async"in n?n.async:!0;d.open(n.type,n.url,T,n
.username,n.password);for(r in f)y.apply(d,f[r]);return n.timeout>0&&(j=setTimeo
ut(function(){d.onreadystatechange=x,d.abort(),v(null,"timeout",d,n,o)},n.timeou
t)),d.send(n.data?n.data:null),d},t.get=function(){return t.ajax(j.apply(null,ar
guments))},t.post=function(){var e=j.apply(null,arguments);return e.type="POST",
t.ajax(e)},t.getJSON=function(){var e=j.apply(null,arguments);return e.dataType=
"json",t.ajax(e)},t.fn.load=function(e,n,i){if(!this.length)return this;var a,r=
this,s=e.split(/\s/),u=j(e,n,i),f=u.success;return s.length>1&&(u.url=s[0],a=s[1
]),u.success=function(e){r.html(a?t("<div>").html(e.replace(o,"")).find(a):e),f&
&f.apply(r,arguments)},t.ajax(u),this};var T=encodeURIComponent;t.param=function
(t,e){var n=[];return n.add=function(t,e){this.push(T(t)+"="+T(e))},S(n,t,e),n.j
oin("&").replace(/%20/g,"+")}}(Zepto),function(t){t.fn.serializeArray=function()
{var n,e=[];return t([].slice.call(this.get(0).elements)).each(function(){n=t(th
is);var i=n.attr("type");"fieldset"!=this.nodeName.toLowerCase()&&!this.disabled
&&"submit"!=i&&"reset"!=i&&"button"!=i&&("radio"!=i&&"checkbox"!=i||this.checked
)&&e.push({name:n.attr("name"),value:n.val()})}),e},t.fn.serialize=function(){va
r t=[];return this.serializeArray().forEach(function(e){t.push(encodeURIComponen
t(e.name)+"="+encodeURIComponent(e.value))}),t.join("&")},t.fn.submit=function(e
){if(e)this.bind("submit",e);else if(this.length){var n=t.Event("submit");this.e
q(0).trigger(n),n.isDefaultPrevented()||this.get(0).submit()}return this}}(Zepto
),function(t){"__proto__"in{}||t.extend(t.zepto,{Z:function(e,n){return e=e||[],
t.extend(e,t.fn),e.selector=n||"",e.__Z=!0,e},isZ:function(e){return"array"===t.
type(e)&&"__Z"in e}});try{getComputedStyle(void 0)}catch(e){var n=getComputedSty
le;window.getComputedStyle=function(t){try{return n(t)}catch(e){return null}}}}(
Zepto);
</script>
    <script>Zepto(function($) {
  prettyPrint();

  var $frameContainer = $('.frames-container');
  var $container      = $('.details-container');
  var $activeLine     = $frameContainer.find('.frame.active');
  var $activeFrame    = $container.find('.frame-code.active');
  var headerHeight    = $('header').height();

  var highlightCurrentLine = function() {
    // Highlight the active and neighboring lines for this frame:
    var activeLineNumber = +($activeLine.find('.frame-line').text());
    var $lines           = $activeFrame.find('.linenums li');
    var firstLine        = +($lines.first().val());

    $($lines[activeLineNumber - firstLine - 1]).addClass('current');
    $($lines[activeLineNumber - firstLine]).addClass('current active');
    $($lines[activeLineNumber - firstLine + 1]).addClass('current');
  }

  // Highlight the active for the first frame:
  highlightCurrentLine();

  $frameContainer.on('click', '.frame', function() {
    var $this  = $(this);
    var id     = /frame\-line\-([\d]*)/.exec($this.attr('id'))[1];
    var $codeFrame = $('#frame-code-' + id);

    if ($codeFrame) {
      $activeLine.removeClass('active');
      $activeFrame.removeClass('active');

      $this.addClass('active');
      $codeFrame.addClass('active');

      $activeLine  = $this;
      $activeFrame = $codeFrame;

      highlightCurrentLine();

      $container.scrollTop(headerHeight);
    }
  });

  if (typeof ZeroClipboard !== "undefined") {
          ZeroClipboard.config({
                  moviePath: '//ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/1.3.5/Zer
oClipboard.swf',
          });

          var clipEl = document.getElementById("copy-button");
          var clip = new ZeroClipboard( clipEl );
          var $clipEl = $(clipEl);

          // show the button, when swf could be loaded successfully from CDN
          clip.on("load", function() {
                  $clipEl.show();
          });
  }
});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

At first I thought was because It uses single quote instead of double quotes, but It seems it's not the case here. Btw, I'm using Windows Command Prompt.

Comment: Post the route and the controller that your using, btw post your code and not the tutorial code.

Comment: my code and the tutorial code is exactly the same.

Comment: The tutorial link may go dead and we want future users to fully understand your problem.

Comment: I just found out the problem. The person who wrote the tutorial had a type with url and urls(plural) that makes the whole things not working.